# Convert sql Query to LINQ return always null

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this sql Query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Incentivos].[dbo].[Incentivos] AS I 
  INNER JOIN [Incentivos].[dbo].[Captura] AS C ON I.CapturaID = C.ID
  WHERE I.EmpleadoID =4530 and C.mdEstatusRegistro = 1
```

It works correctly, now I want to use it with LINQ, so I try

```
  var ce = _contexto.Empleados.Where(x => x.nCodigoEmpleado == codigoEmpleado)
           .Select(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault(); //4530 value

 var captura = _contexto.Capturas.Where(x => x.mdEstatusRegistro).ToList(); //Captura table

  //JOIN
  var Incentivo = _contexto.Incentivos 
  .Join(captura, x => x.CapturaID, y => y.ID, (x, y) => new { x, y })
  .Where(x => x.y.mdEstatusRegistro && x.x.EmpleadoID == ce)
  .Select(b=> b.x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Problem is Join always come null, what am I doing wrong? regards

**UPDATE:**
I change query more simple like

```
 var Incentivo = from incentivos in _contexto.Incentivos
                 join captura in _contexto.Capturas on incentivos.CapturaID equals captura.ID
                 where (incentivos.EmpleadoID == ce) && (captura.mdEstatusRegistro == true)
                 select incentivos;
```

But now after query I want to access Incentivo like:

```
Incentivo.nPorcentajeAJU //Property of Incentivo table
```

But I can't , how can I access variables now?

Comment: I can't get more than one value because this `AND C.mdEstatusRegistro = 1` validation in sql just return one value @DavidG

Comment: try to replace **x.nCodigoEmpleado == (int)codigoEmpleado** with **SqlFunctions.StringConvert(x.nCodigoEmpleado)==codigoEmpleado**

Comment: @DavidG No it won't.  `FirstOrDefault` only returns the default value for an empty set, otherwise it returns the first item.

Comment: But it should get a value. like sql instruction, it's supposed I'm reply it but with LINQ @juharr

Comment: You really shoudn't do the `ToList` for the `captura` as that pulls the data into memory.  Also you should look into using navigation properties instead of joins https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: @juharr Oh my, I am losing it today.... d'oh!

Comment: @Pepe *don't* convert SQL to LINQ. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL, it's a query language that sits on top of an ORM like EF. It's the **ORM's business** to generate the joins from the navigation properties in the classes. If you have to use joins, your classes are wrong

Comment: @Pepe you shouldn't have to write anything more than `contexto.Empleados.Where(emp=>emp.Captura.mdEstatusRegistro  && emp.EmpleadoID==4530)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I update my question

Comment: I update my question @juharr

Comment: @Pepe it's still wrong. The `Incentivos` class should have a `Capturas` property or collection. The ORM will generate the joins. If the classes and properties are named using EF's conventions you won't even have to configure the DbContext

Comment: Incentivo class have  public `Captura Captura { get; set; }` property but when I try `contexto.Empleados.Where(emp=>emp.Captura.mdEstatusRegistro && emp.EmpleadoID==4530)` I cant access to `emp.Captura` @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @Pepe then post your code, including your context configuration and explain the actual problem - `I can't access to` isn't a compile or runtime error. Don't assume you are the first to find a crippling bug in EF. There's nothing wrong with mappings and properties

Comment: Are Incentivos and Captura properly related in the database? Im guessing you have the CapturaID as a foreign key on Incentivos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ query will always return a `List<Incentivos>`, so the only way you can access `Incentivo.nPorcentajeAJU` is in a `foreach` loop. However as you state query only returns one record then you must write like this:

```
var Incentivo = (
  from incentivos in _contexto.Incentivos
  join captura in _contexto.Capturas on incentivos.CapturaID equals captura.ID
  where (incentivos.EmpleadoID == ce) && (captura.mdEstatusRegistro == true)
  select incentivos
).First<Incentivos>();

int someVar = Incentivo.Some_Property; //Access the property like so
```